# Autofilter not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 13 row range with the first row a header row and the next 12 rows filled in by a QueryTable. The query will return at most 12 rows, but possibly less. Below this range I have a totals row.

I want to hide any rows that do not have data and I'm using AutoFilter to do this. When I run the code it creates the AutoFilter but doesn't apply the criteria. If I step through the code, it works just fine. Any ideas?

```
Sub fillTable()
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    Sheet15.AutoFilterMode = False

    Sheet15.Range("DCRTable").ClearContents
    strConn = "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=<db path>;"
    Set qt = Sheet15.QueryTables.Add(strConn, Sheet15.Range("DCRTable"))
    qt.CommandText = <sql query>
    qt.AdjustColumnWidth = False
    qt.EnableRefresh = False
    qt.FieldNames = False
    qt.Refresh

    hideEmpties Sheet15.Range("DCRTable").offset(-1).Resize(13)
End Sub

Sub hideEmpties(rng As Range)
    rng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I cannot see how you assigned your sheet to object "Sheet15" - maybe this is part of the problem. If you have a named range, you don't need a Sheet object before that.

Secondly, .Autofilter with no arguments just toggles the Autofilter arrow on/off, and you loose your criteria.

Try this code, it worked for me (Office 2003) ... I have a header in A1, followed by A2..A13 named as DRCTable, followed by a =SUM(DRCTable) in A14

**edit 02-Jan-2010**

*(sorry I can't test ODBC from my holiday domicile so this part is tested only syntactically)*

```
Sub fillTable()
Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range
Dim MyQRY As QueryTable, MyCONNECT As String, MySELECT As String ' added 02-Jan-2010

    'initialize
    Set MySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set MyRange = Range("DRCTable")

    MyCONNECT = "ODBC;..."           ' added 02-Jan-2010
    MySELECT = "SELECT * FROM DUAL"  ' added 02-Jan-2010 .. noticed my Oracle past :) ??

    Set MyQRY = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=MyCONNECT, _
                                            Destination:=MyRange, _
                                            Sql:=MySELECT)

    ' clean up
    MySheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    MyRange.ClearContents

    ' simulate Query      removed 02-Jan-2010
    ' MyRange(1, 1) = 1   removed 02-Jan-2010
    ' MyRange(2, 1) = 2   removed 02-Jan-2010
    ' MyRange(3, 1) = 3   removed 02-Jan-2010
    ' MyRange(4, 1) = 4   removed 02-Jan-2010
    ' MyRange(5, 1) = 5   removed 02-Jan-2010

    ' added 02-Jan-2010
    ' BackgroundQuery = FALSE waits until query is executed
    '                 = TRUE continues with VBA once connection to DB is made

    MyQRY.BackgroundQuery = False ' set this to affect all subsequet refresh
                                  ' and don't use the bool in refresh except
                                  ' to override the setting

    MyQRY.Refresh False ' the false sets BackgroundQuery for the individual refresh;
                        ' there is no default on this param within the refresh method.
                        ' If unspecified here the QueryTable.BackgroundQuery property
                        ' is examined

    ' select data range plus header and filter
    Range(MyRange.Offset(-1, 0), MyRange(12, 1)).AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

End Sub
```

Hope that helps
Good luck MikeD

Comment: Thanks. Sheet15 is the code name for the worksheet object. It's the preferred way to reference sheets. It is standard best practice to form the AutoFilter without criteria first, then add the criteria later. The problem appears to be one of timing; if I step through the code, it works. If I run it all at once, it doesn't.

Comment: in tis case, try to make use of the "BackgroundQuery" property, i.e. set it FALSE before applying the .Refresh method. This may be just a safety precaution, but I couldn't clearly see what is the default for this property. Set to TRUE the script execution commences once the **connection** is made, not when all rows are returned (which is what you want). Good luck MikeD

Comment: Sorry I bailed on this for so long. That suggestion appears to have worked. If you edit your original solution to match your comment, I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: welcome! I now invoked the BackgroundQuery thing into the post. **** Happy New Year 2010 ****